# py script stop after execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I have the following script:

```
import time
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

STATUS=False
COMBINATION={keyboard.Key.esc, keyboard.Key.alt}

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()

def on_press(key):
    if key in COMBINATION:
        current.add(key)
        if all(k in current for k in COMBINATION):
            STATUS = False
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        STATUS = True

def on_release(key):
    try:
        current.remove(key)
    except KeyError:
        pass

def hp(delay):
    keyboard.press(Key.f1)
    keyboard.release(Key.f1)
    time.sleep(delay)

def cp():
    keyboard.press(Key.f2)
    keyboard.release(Key.f2)

def main():
    with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()
    while True:
        while STATUS:
            for i in range(3):
                hp(0.5)
            cp()
```

when I generate an executable with pyinstaller or even run it through the end with python3, the script simply doesn't loop as I had thought (run forever)
as I don't have any err messages, I don't know where my err might be, can anyone help?

Comment: Well, you didn't call the ```main()```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an entry point for your script.
Add this to the bottom of you file, and try again:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```